# how to remove a css class dynamically in ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ion-toggle

i'm using in my ionic project a ion-toggle, when i open the app in the browser the ion-toggle's html generated is:

```
<div class="noToggleBorder item item-toggle toggle-large ng-empty ng-valid" ng-model="checkarrivee.boo[var.id]" ng-click="checkarrivee.isMissionSelected(var.id,checkarrivee.ficheDeMission.id)" toggle-class="toggle-positive">
    <div ng-transclude=""><span class="ng-binding">Ceintures De Sécurités Passagères</span></div>
    <label class="toggle toggle-positive disable-user-behavior">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkarrivee.boo[var.id]" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
        <div class="track">
            <div class="handle"></div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

My question is: How i can remove the item class from this div dynamically??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div class="noToggleBorder item-toggle toggle-large ng-empty ng-valid" ng-class="{item: checkValue()}" ng-model="checkarrivee.boo[var.id]" ng-click="checkarrivee.isMissionSelected(var.id,checkarrivee.ficheDeMission.id)" toggle-class="toggle-positive">
<div ng-transclude=""><span class="ng-binding">Ceintures De Sécurités Passagères</span></div>
<label class="toggle toggle-positive disable-user-behavior">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkarrivee.boo[var.id]" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
    <div class="track">
        <div class="handle"></div>
    </div>
</label>
</div>
```

put 'item' class in ng-class and depend on expression show the item class.

Answer (score 0):

To remove atributes:

element.removeAttribute("style")

$('#TheIdOfTheElement').removeAttr('style'');

If you want to change classes or to modify them you should check ng-class:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

```
<ANY class="ng-class: expression;"> ... </ANY>
```

Comment: is there a way by angularjs??

Comment: Yes, use ng-class. see my code  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40213764/how-to-remove-a-css-class-dynamically-in-ionic/40213956#40213956

Comment: i tried to use this but it doesnt work..i tried this $("#tog .item").removeClass("item"); but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

$("#Selector").removeClass("class Name"); 
for example :
i use this line to remove col-sm-2 class from my selector (divId .col-sm-2)
 $("#divId .col-sm-2").removeClass("col-sm-2");

Comment: thank you Ammar for the answer but it doesnt work....i tried this  $("#tog .item").removeClass("item"); but it doesnt work